# c# access child class from parent

Tags: c#, list, class

I have two classes. Jewellery is base and Ring inherits from it.

```
class Jewellery 
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     ......

     public Jewellery(string name) 
     {
          Name = name;
     }
}
```

.

```
class Ring : Jewellery
{
     public string Size { get; set; }

     public Ring(string name, string size) :base(name)
     {
          Size = size
     }
}
```

Now in main i created List of Jewellery and in that list i added Ring object.

```
Ring ring = new Ring("Diamond", "Very big");
List<Jewellery> jewellery = new List<Jewellery>();
jewellery.Add(ring);
```

Now when debugging i can access ring object from jewellery list. Can i do it from code? I think this should be done like this, but this doesn't work.

```
jewellery[0].Ring
```

Comment: It sounds lik a basic oop question. Google virtual methods, overriding, and  visitor pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast it, e.g.:

```
var myRing = (Ring)jewellery[0];
```

or

```
var maybeRing = jewellery[0] as Ring;
if (maybeRing != null)
{
 // do stuff
}
```

or

```
if (jewellery[0] is Ring)
{
   // Cast and do stuff
}
```

For multiple types you can

```
if (jewellery[0] is Ring)
{
   // Cast and do stuff
}
else if(jewllery[0] is Necklace)
{
  // and so on
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx) on safe casting.

---

Depending on what you want to do you can use Linq to filter by type:

Given:

```
List<Jewellery> things = new List<Jewllery>();
```

Then:

```
public IList<T> GetJewellery<T>(this jewellery) where T : Jewellery
{
    return jewellery.OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

Can:

```
IList<Necklace> necklaces = things.GetJewellery<Necklace>();
IList<Ring> rings = things.GetJewellery<Ring>();
```

Comment: But if i have more classes? And then i wouldn't know what first element is. For example, i have `class Necklace : Jewellery` and i add it to list `jewellery.Add(necklace);`. And now i want to sort list and access first item. So now i don't know if it is ring or necklace.